# Schema-awareness and streaming

Tags: saxon, xslt-3.0

I am in the process of converting a schema-aware stylesheet into streaming XSLT3. One thing I'm pleasantly surprised about is that it appears that streaming and schema-awareness work together. I can do `instance of` checks on grounded nodes (or even template match rules) for example and get the correct result. What is less clear is *how* this happens. Is the document run through multiple passes? Also, I notice that I can do `id()` and `idref()` operations on a captured accumulator (a very good thing), but it is unclear why (I'm not copying a document-node).

Comment: Why would instance of not work on grounded nodes? `copy-of` https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#func-copy-of preserves the validated type.

Comment: I never said it didn't work, rather that it *did*. I guess I was more surprised that it knows the type of items as they are being streamed, which doesn't seem possible without multiple passes.

Comment: I think the type of an element is known when parsing the start tag, the validity is only known when parsing the whole element. https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#streamed-validation says "The XSD specification is designed so that validation is, with one or two exceptions, a streamable process." and "XSD is designed so that the intended type of an element (the “governing type”) can be determined as soon as the start tag of the element is encountered"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "instance of" test is provisional: it's testing the type annotation of the node on the assumption that it will turn out to be valid. If it doesn't turn out to be valid, your code will be aborted in due course, because validation errors are fatal. This is why try/catch on validation can only catch the error at the level of the validation episode as a whole, it can't recover at a finer-grained level.

I'm not sure off-hand about the id() and idref() tests, but I suspect it's because a captured accumulator is effectively taking a snapshot() of the streamed node, and a snapshot is rooted at a document node. Presumably idref() will only work if the reference is within the snapshot.